# change event on a table fails in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, delegation

I am using jQuery to capture a change event on a table.  The table has many rows and each row has a few inputs boxes and a checkbox.  To do this, I am using event delegation.  I am capturing any changes at the tbody level.  This is the code below

```
$j('#orderItems tbody').change(function (event) {
    var target = $j(event.target);
    var nodeName = $j(target).attr('nodeName').toLowerCase();
    if (nodeName == 'input') {
        if ($j(target).hasClass('partnum')) {
            var val = $j(target).attr('value');
            dsOrder.getItem(target);
            dsOrder.updateActiveIndex(target);
        }
        if ($j(target).hasClass('qty')) {
            var val = $j(target).attr('value');
            dsOrder.updateQty(target);
            dsOrder.updateActiveIndex(target);
        }
        if ($j(target).hasClass('unitprice')) {
            var val = $j(target).attr('value');
            dsOrder.updatePrice(target);
            dsOrder.updateActiveIndex(target);
        }
    }
})
```

This code works fine in Firefox, but the change event is not captured in IE. I would like to approach this solution using event delegation rather than attaching each event onto each input element.  I also would like to avoid targeting each element using jQuery as the table rows are built dynamically and unbinding/binding events seems a little messy (just my opinion)

Any ideas on how to get this to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're actually using bubbling to pick up the event on the ancestor element, not capturing (which IE doesn't support and jQuery doesn't use). Unfortunately whilst `onchange` [bubbles in the DOM spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html#Events-eventgroupings-htmlevents) it [does not in IE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536912(VS.85).aspx).

I think you will just have to target the inputs. (Unfortunately the ‘live’ function doesn't support onchange, either.)